# Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP Org1MSP is unknown (IBM Container Service)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I did the following tutorial (https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/) to get fabric running on kube and am trying to query my blockchain.

I tried to set up my user like this:

```
function getAdmin(client, options) {
    return Promise.resolve(client.createUser({
        username: 'admin',
        mspid: 'Org1MSP',
        cryptoContent: {
            privateKeyPEM:  // am not sure what goes here but I put the blockchain-org1-peer private key and cert
            signedCertPEM: 
        }
    }));
}
```

When I try to query my blockchain, I get the error: MSP Org1MSP is unknown. I have seen other answers, and they say to upgrade Docker, but I cannot do this on IBM Container Service.

What causes this error and what are solutions I can try? Most tutorials show `Org1MSP`, but this could be wrong. How do I check the MSP on Kube? When I `env` in Kube I see: `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP`

Comment: how did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

We have custom network on IBM Blockchain and I have installed our chaincode on one of the peers which is joined to one of the channels.

Then I tried to invoke some chaincode functions (see code below).

```
var request = {
    targets: peerNames,
    chaincodeId: chaincodeName,
    fcn: fcn,
    args: args,
    chainId: channelName,
    txId: tx_id
};

let results = await channel.sendTransactionProposal(request);

let proposalResponses = results[0];
let proposal = results[1];
```

I was getting errors because I was targeting all of the peers on the channel, but just one of those had the right chaincode installed on it.

The solution was to remove all peers that don't have the right chaincode installed.

Not sure how much control over network and fabric client do you have in that example, but double check where your cc is installed.